# Negative impacts of using GC_malloc_explicitly_typed

Tags: c, garbage-collection, boehm-gc

I have a substantial C project that has been using the Boehm GC for a while now; it was built from scratch, and it has used the Boehm GC since day one, and its type-allocation behavior is well-known.

Currently, it uses `GC_MALLOC()` and `GC_MALLOC_ATOMIC()`, and it has acceptable (tolerable) performance.  But because all of its types are well-known, and the project is generally isolated from the rest of the C ecosystem (it doesn't link anything outside libc), it seems not unreasonable to me to switch the project over to primarily use `GC_malloc_explicitly_typed()`.  Many of the project's types mix-and-match raw values and pointers, so in theory, this *should* provide a performance boost during a collection by allowing the collector to be precise instead of conservative on all the types allocated through it.  (It may not be a *lot* of a performance boost, but I still want to be as nice to the garbage collector as I can.)

That said, `gc_typed.h` has all sorts of warning messages at the top about using `GC_malloc_explicitly_typed()`:

```
/*
 * Some simple primitives for allocation with explicit type information.
 * Facilities for dynamic type inference may be added later.
 * Should be used only for extremely performance critical applications,
 * or if conservative collector leakage is otherwise a problem (unlikely).
 * Note that this is implemented completely separately from the rest
 * of the collector, and is not linked in unless referenced.
 * This does not currently support GC_DEBUG in any interesting way.
 */
```

and this:

```
/* Returns a conservative approximation in the          */
/* (unlikely) case of insufficient memory to build      */
/* the descriptor.  Calls to GC_make_descriptor         */
/* may consume some amount of a finite resource.  This  */
/* is intended to be called once per type, not once     */
/* per allocation.                                      */
```

I'm really not convinced any of those are issues for me, and my code *is* performance-critical, and the collector *does* come up hot in some of my profiling.  I don't think I need `GC_DEBUG` — leastaways, I've never felt the need to debug the heap.  I have no problem with invoking `GC_make_descriptor()` for every type I need to allocate, and I have no problem with invoking that function a predictable constant number of times at program startup.

It seems like my code is a perfect candidate for using `GC_malloc_explicitly_typed()`, but the number and scope of those warning messages still give me pause, and they almost seem to imply that the `explicitly_typed` function will at some point be deleted in favor of a "better" interface.  So my question is simply:

**Has anyone using `GC_malloc_explicitly_typed()` found any unstated or non-obvious drawbacks to using it?**